# Skip a whole file conditionally with doctest

Tags: python, pytest, doctest, tox, f-string

I wrote a sphinx `.rst` file whith doctest snippets using f-strings. I use tox to test my project and my documentation with several versions of python, and pytest to run the tests with `pytest --doctest-glob='*.rst'`. Some of the python versions I run the tests on are not supporting f-strings (2.7 and 3.5). I need to skip this file with old python versions.

The `:skipif:` and `:pyversion:` in the code blocks are ineffective, and I get the following error when used:

```
UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: SyntaxError('invalid syntax', (hello = "hello {foobar} world")'))
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/doctest.py", line 1321, in __run
    compileflags, 1), test.mytest)

  File "<doctest myfile.rst[1]>", line 1

    hello = "hello {foobar} world"
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
myfile.rst:26: UnexpectedException
```

The test and the tox configuration are very generic:

```
# setup.cfg
[tox:tox]
envlist=py27,py35,py36,py37,py38
```

```
# myfile.rst
>>> foobar = "foobar"
>>> hello = f"hello {foobar} world"
```

How can I prevent the whole file to be tested, or even parsed, without explicitly ignoring it with pytest?

Comment: The only way is to exclude the file from tests completely. You showed us neither code nor `tox.ini` so we hardly could help.

Comment: I wanted to keep my question short. My tox configuration is the most generic one can have. `[tox:tox]envlist=py27,py35,py36,py37,py38`

Comment: For `{py27,py35}` exclude the file from testing. You didn't show the command(s) used to run tests. If it's, e.g. `pytest` use `pytest --ignore=/path/to/test.py`.

Comment: I edited the question to be more precise. Ignoring each file explicitly with pytest is a bit tedious, I would prefer using a sphinx tag like `:skipif:` or `:pyversion:`.

Comment: "*I would prefer using a sphinx tag like :skipif: or :pyversion:*" That's impossible. To get to the marks the file must be parsed first. And if parser raises `SyntaxError` that's the end of the story. The file is rejected completely. No syntax, no marks.

Comment: Ok I guess I have my answer then. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe better luck with some plugins such as [pytest-sphinx](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-sphinx/), or [sybil](https://pypi.org/project/sybil/). These might take into account the `:pyversion:` option.